# Error (Could not find the inverse association for profile_image_attachment (:record in ActiveStorage::Attachment)):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-activestorage

In my `app/models/active_storage/attachment.rb` file I had used this code

```
class ActiveStorage::Attachment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :blob, class_name: "ActiveStorage::Blob

  def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
    ["blob_id", "created_at", "id", "name", "record_id", "record_type"]
  end
end
```

When creating Active Admin with Active Storage, I encountered a search error. To address this, I used  defined the ransackable method in my model. In my `app/models/user.rb` I had used

```
has_one_attached :profile_image
```

When I open this link http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/1 it show this error:

```
unknown keywords: :class_name, :as, :inverse_of
```

And when I open this link http://127.0.0.1:3000/admin it open successfully

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huNJR.png)

I had used inverse of in my `app/models/user.rb` file, but it did't work I had go through all my schema file it generate activestorage of correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't define or redefine any association in built-in `ActiveStorage::Attachment` class. And of course you shouldn't change inheritance of this class!

Look to the [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/77f7b8ce89ab77cd8d40f682470cb36a2ace0271/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/attachment.rb) and you will see that parent class is `ActiveStorage::Record`. And `belongs_to :blob` has `autosave` option

If you need to allow search with ransack, just reopen this class with ransack method. Define only ransack method, don't change other things

You can use initializer to patch built-in classes

```rb
# config/initializers/active_storage.rb

ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_storage_attachment) do
  class ActiveStorage::Attachment < ActiveStorage::Record
    def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
      %w[blob_id created_at id name record_id record_type]
    end
  end
end
```

Please note `on_load` hook here, it is from source code above. And it is important moment because you can successfully patch only if needed class is already loaded

<sub>Also note that inheritance is different in older rails: `ActiveStorage::Attachment`'s parent class in [5.2](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/attachment.rb) and [6.0](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6-0-stable/activestorage/app/models/active_storage/attachment.rb) versions is `ActiveRecord::Base`. And 5.2 doesn't support hooks</sub>